# Ajax page cannot find function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript page which loads a page via ajax into a JQuery tab.

When I try and call a function which exists in the parent page from page loaded via ajax it complains it cannot find the function.

Is this normal behaviour and does anyone have a way around this?

For example:

```
      function test() {
      My code here...
      }

function openMainGridRecord(Sequence,Module) {

        $('#Tabs').jqxTabs('addLast', 'View Record*', '<div id=new' + index + ' style="height:99%"></div>')
        loadTabData('editrecord.php', index);
        index++;

    }

       loadPage('mainGrid.php', 2);
```

My page called mainGrid.php also has javascript in it, but I would like to call a function that exists on the page above.

So I would like some javascript inside mainGrid.php to call my test() function.
Thanks

Comment: write your code.. what are you trying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you describe I believe I know the issue. What is loaded in the parent page is not loaded in the page called by the Ajax request. PHP is stateless, that is to say every time a page is opened it is a fresh page with no data loaded.

When you make an Ajax request you are, in effect, opening a new page on the server. That is why you cannot access the function on the parent page.

The solution is to have a common file available to both pages (using `include`) and then put the function in that file. Include it at the top of the parent page and at the top of the Ajax page.